# I want to change the state of a single book in my react app but it changes state of the whole array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am creating this books react app that tracks your reading progress by having three different shelves i.e. Currently Reading, Read and Want to Read.
Now, When I change the value of the state, it updates the state of the whole array.
[image: See when i change the value to want to read]
[image: all the books shift to want to read instead of only one]
This is the code of WantToRead.js which is similar to currentlyReading.js and Read.js the only difference being the value of shelf in state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as BooksAPI from "../BooksAPI";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";
import "../App.css";

    class WantToRead extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showSearchPage: false,
          shelf: "wantToRead",
          data: {},
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
      handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ shelf: event.target.value });
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
        const booksData = await BooksAPI.getAll();
        this.setState({ data: booksData.data });
      }
      render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        console.log(data.books);
        if (data.books === undefined) {
          return <Spinner />;
        } else {
          const shelfItems = data.books.map((book) => {
            if (book.shelf === "wantToRead") {
              BooksAPI.update(book, this.state.shelf);
              const thumbnail = book.imageLinks.thumbnail;
              console.log(book.title);
              return (
                <ol className="books-grid">
                  <li>
                    <div key={book.title}>
                      <div className="book">
                        <div className="book-top">
                          <div
                            className="book-cover"
                            style={{
                              width: 128,
                              height: 193,
                              backgroundImage: "url(" + thumbnail + ")",
                            }}
                          />
                          <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                            <select
                              value={this.state.shelf}
                              onChange={this.handleChange}
                            >
                              <option value="move" disabled>
                                Move to...
                              </option>
                              <option value="currentlyReading">
                                Currently Reading
                              </option>
                              <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                              <option value="read">Read</option>
                              <option value="none">None</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                        <div className="book-authors">{book.authors[0]}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              );
            }
          });
          return <div className="container">{shelfItems}</div>;
        }
      }
    }
    
    export default WantToRead;
```

This is the api call for updating shelf value:

```
export const update = (book, shelf) =>
  fetch(`${api}/books/${book.id}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ shelf }),
  }).then((res) => res.json());
```

Comment: `Now, When I change the value of the state` where is it in the code? is it `handleChange`?

Comment: The handleChange method changes the value of state which in turn is used by the update method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this when you change the state for the shelf, you are also updating the shelf for all the items to 'want to read'.
Initially, all the items will have 'Currently Reading' and `if (book.shelf === "CurrentlyReading")` is always returning true for all the items.

```
          const shelfItems = data.books.map((book) => {
            if (book.shelf === "CurrentlyReading") {
              BooksAPI.update(book, this.state.shelf);
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I update the state of an individual book? That was my question.